# countdown timer should not stop

Tags: javascript

This is the code for countdown I am using . If the user reloads the page the countdown starts again .
I want  the countdown to keep on running after the first time user has visited that page irrespective whether he closes the page or not . Please suggest a method . I think creating sessions might help but I have no idea about sessions .

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<script>
var seconds =120;
function secondPassed() {
var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
}
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('bonus').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
} else {
    seconds--;
}
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: you could drop a cookie when they first visit of the time the counter started. On subsequent visits, just offset the countdown from this time.

Comment: Since you don't know at which point the user will close the window or refresh the page, you'll need to save the counter with every tick in some persistent storage such as a cookie (best cross browser solution), local storage etc. Next time the page loads start with the last saved value

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely complete. You want a counter for "forever" or for "a while after he accessed page first time".

For the first one, you need to count on the server side (you can for example create a db - or a file, or whatever you are comfortable with for saving things), and somehow identify the user, and get the first time he accessed. Then send back this info each time user logs, and count on client side in js, just like you do.

For the second one, you can either send a cookie with the timestamp he accessed first time, either save this info in session and use it each time user access the page.

Comment: This is what I want : Once the usser enters the site ,the countdown should continue irrespective whether the webpage is reloaded or closed . I don't want the timer to start again from the previous time he left the page .It should go on and on . Also , I tried learning about cookies from W3 schools . I couldnt get much help . If I could get a sample code , it would be good